# Ubuntu 14.04LTS running Kodi random freezes

Tags: intel-graphics, hdmi, kodi

I am running Ubuntu on my media center.
It has Kodi running and it is on 24/7 - well when it runs.
It will freeze randomly while being idle, never while it is running anything on Kodi.
When it freezes you can hear small click/static-y sounds from the TV where it is hooked up to via HDMI.
It hasn't been able to run 2 days straight without a freeze since I have installed Ubuntu.

My system specifications are:

- Intel i7 4770
- Gigabyte Z87-D3HP motherboard
- 16GB HyperX Blu memory
- Intel series 330 SSD 120gb (where Ubuntu is installed)
- WD Blue 2TB for media
- XFX 650W Bronze semi-modular PSU

It's using the onboard Intel HD 4600 graphics. (I have installed no drivers for it, I simply couldn't find any.)

EDIT: When it freezes I cannot SSH into the machine.

How do I go about troubleshooting the issue? My experiences with Linux are limited, it has been very on and off the last 10 years.

Comment: Try running `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:team-xbmc/ppa && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`.  The version of Kodi in the Ubuntu repos is outdated, so this will install the latest version from the official Kodi PPA.

Comment: I've already added the kodi repository before I downloaded Kodi so it is the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with the HDMI sound.

If everything is set to defaults it doesn't freeze. It has been running 3 days now without a hiccup.

If I set the sound to HDMI instead of the default pulseaudio it freezes.
I am running with the defaults now and everything seems to work just as it should.